# c# dynamic lambda expression comparing by date not by DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm in the process of the creation of a dynamic lambda expression
i want to make a comparison by date not DateTime

since there are no type Date in C#, when i create Expression constant

```
var dateexpr = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDateTime(filter.FilterValue).Date, typeof(DateTime));
```

and i run my code -->

my lambda expression look like this

```
query.where(e=>e.createdOn>2016-06-06 00:00:00.000)
```

the time exist always

how can i make the comparison run only by date

Expected Expression:

```
query.where(e=>e.createdOn>2016-06-06)
```

Comment: Question could be clearer if you included how your expected expression looks like.

Comment: Expected Expression  query.where(e=>e.createdOn>2016-06-06)

Comment: Do you want the query to operate in memory, or is this against a database (for example, using Linq to entities)?

Comment: this against a database, i use Nhibernate mapping by  code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, think of the logic. For `greater than`:

```
e.createdOn > 2016-06-06
```

Is exactly the same as querying (notice the `7`):

```
e.createdOn >= 2016-06-07 00:00:00.000
```

So, for `greater than` just add one day to the filter date:

```
var dateexpr = Expression.Constant(
                 Convert.ToDateTime(filter.FilterValue).Date.AddDays(1),
                 typeof(DateTime)
               );
```

For `less than` it'd work with your original expression.

And for `equals` you'd need to compose the expression:

```
e.createdOn >= (your_dateexpression) && e.createdOn < (the expression with one more day)
```

I'll let you figure out `less than or equal` and `greater than or equal`, but just thinking of the logic would do :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as far as I am aware, just whenever you use the comparison on `DateTime` objects check against the `Date` property. For example:

```
if (DateTime1 == DateTime2) { //Date and time match }

else if (DateTime1.Date == DateTime2.Date) { //Date only matches }
```

Comment: the problem that is a constant of expression, therfore i should specify the type and the property is dynamic too then i can't add (.Date) in this dynamic query  query.where(e=>e.createdOn.date>2016-06-06 00:00:00.000)

Comment: How we can do this with dynamic lambda expression